# API сайта для приложения на Android

Tags: php, android, api

Возможно вопрос сформулировал не совсем корректно но суть вопроса такова: Есть сайт с новостями, различными статьями, фотогалереей. Я думаю написать 2-3 php файла, которые будут запросом получать эти самые новости, статьи и ссылки на картинки и декодировать их в JSON, а уже в Android приложении парсить этот JSON и выводить в список и т.д.

Скажите пожалуйста, эти самые php Файлы могут считаться API к этому сайту или нет? Если нет, то как составить API расскажите на словах пожалуйста. Я мало что понял про REST API может не нашел нормальной статьи по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.То куда ты будешь обращаться с андроида тоесть ты будешь посылать запрос и получать ответ это место которое принимает запрос и выдает ответ является твоим рестом*Это грубая формулировка но для начального понятия его хватит

Comment: Если я правильно понял ответ, то такие php файлы, которые делают выборку и выдают в ответ json можно считать API? А если новостей допустим 10 тысяч грубо говоря есть ли способ или библиотеки, которые распарсят такой большой json? А то через asynctask долго парсилось, как-то я проверял.

Comment: Знаешь ли обычно так много файлов не посылают для того ты и пишешь сервисы чтоб телефон парсил только нужные данные .Если обьем данных велик то увы тут даже оптимизация не сильно поможет

Comment: если мой ответ помог палец вверх)

Comment: Я просто спрашиваю про 10 тысяч, я конечно столько данных не получал и не парсил, но порядка 500 новостей было наверное. Можешь ответить коротко да или нет на этот вопрос? выше мной описанные php могут считаться api? Чтобы я точно знал))

Comment: да конечноэто и есть APİ

Comment: 500 новостей это ничего)сожрет быстро

Comment: все, большое спасибо за ответ)

Comment: 500 новостей не нужно пользователю. Он всё равно не сможет их все прочитать. Для такого делается пагинация - когда api отдаёт данные частями (например по 10 шт.). То есть клиент запрашивает количество и смещение. Если пользователь хочет смотреть дальше, то запрашивается следующая часть.